# Pivot table and read data to entity spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pivot

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      Name       | 2016-01-17 | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-20 |
+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
| CANCELED_ORDERS |         50 |         20 |         30 |
| ORDERS          |        100 |        120 |        150 |
+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

here is the repository  that i want to map to table :

```
@Repository public interface TimeAttandanceRepository extends JpaRepository<TimeAttandance,Long>{

    @Query(value = "{call [sp_load_fingerprint_status_bk](:today)}" ,nativeQuery =true)     List<TimeAttandance>lstTimeAttandance(@Param ("today") String today);    }
```

here is the class that i want to map to table :

```
@Entity
public class TimeAttandance {
    
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String name;

     /* and how can I read column date from my jpaRepository to this entity*/


}
```

I am new pivot to sorry for data please help me